# Uncountable collection of uniform random variables equalling a value

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have a set of independent uniform random variables $\left(U_x, x \in [0,1]\right)$.
Then let $A$ be the event $ \left\{ \exists x : U_x = 1/2 \right\} $

Can find a probability $\mathbb{P}(A)$?

The difficulty is in making sense of what we mean by an uncountable collection of independent random variables. One way we can build these random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is by the [Kolmogorov Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem),
however if we do this then the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ does not contain the event A, so there would be no way to make sense of a probability.

Is there some other construction we can use to make sense of $A$?